# How can I search the local drives for the existence of a directory?

Tags: windows, batch-file

I'm trying to figure out how to determine if the directory "\Program Files (x86)\Apache Software Foundation\Apache2.2" exists on any of the local drives of a Windows 2008 machine.

I thought it'd be something like this:

```
for /f "skip=2 tokens=2 delims=," %%A in (
 'wmic logicaldisk get name /format:csv'
) DO (
  echo %%A
  IF EXIST "%%A\Program Files (x86)\Apache Software Foundation\Apache2.2" (
    echo FOUND ON %%A
  )
)
```

But it simply echos the drive letter.

I'm a Unix guy stuck in a Windows world for this particular project, please help!

---

I got some help from a co-worker, here's how it was solved:

```
SET FOUNDIT=FALSE
SET ERRORLEVEL=

FOR /F "skip=2 tokens=2 usebackq delims=," %%i IN (
    `wmic logicaldisk where "drivetype=3" get name^,size /format:csv`
) DO (
    if /i "%foundit%" equ "true" exit /b
    CALL :APACHE %%i
    if %ERRORLEVEL% equ 0 set FOUNDIT=TRUE
)

IF %FOUNDIT% equ "TRUE" exit /B ELSE exit /B 1

:APACHE
    set DRIVE=%1
    REM echo DRIVE is %DRIVE%
    if "%DRIVE%" equ "" exit /B
    set APACHEPATH=%DRIVE%\Program Files (x86)\Apache Software Foundation\Apache2.2
    IF EXIST "%APACHEPATH%" CALL :FOUNDIT "%APACHEPATH%"

    exit /B

:FOUNDIT
    echo FOUND APACHE on %1
    for /f "tokens=*" %%x in (%1) do set APACHEINSTALLDIR=%%x
    set FOUNDIT=TRUE
    exit /B
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: paths with spaces need to be enclosed in quotes, `"%%A\Program Files (x86)\Apache Software Foundation\Apache2.2"`

Comment: I just updated the code to wrap the IF EXIST file path with quotes, but it's only echoing the %%A, the IF EXISTS isn't finding the directory that exists.

Comment: write `echo -%%A-` instead of `echo %%A` and see the catastrophe... Remove any  `echo off` to see it more clearly.

Comment: Download Cygwin and visit a happy place

Comment: Don't I wish I could just download cygwin, but this is supporting some build processes on Windows servers across the company.

Comment: Does `%%A` include the colon, e.g., `C:` or is it just `C` ?

Comment: @HarryJohnston: it does include the colon, but also an additional CarriageReturn, which makes some trouble. See my answer for details and how to solve it.

Answer (score 3):

wmic has a ugly behaviour: it does not write proper linefeeds, so if you use the last token, you run into problems.

Workaround: don't use the last token (or force it to add another token, that you don't use, here `size`). As you don't use the last token, it doesn't matter that it doesn't end properly

```
for /F "skip=2 tokens=2 delims=," %A in ('wmic logicaldisk where "drivetype=3" get name^,size /format:csv') DO (
```

(you will have to escape the comma).

I added the `where "drivetype=3"`, so it will only check HardDisks (no CD/DVD/Flash), but you can leave this out.

Comment: Thank you for your input, this helped with the solution.

Answer (score 0):

An another way a bit simplist but secure and much more faster as the `WMIC` method :

```
for %%a in (a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z) do (
if exist %%a: (
  IF EXIST "%%a:\Program Files (x86)\Apache Software Foundation\Apache2.2\" (
     echo FOUND ON [%%a:])))
```

Comment: faster? maybe. But it asks me to "insert Disk" several times.