# Get screen resolution as a variable in cmd

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, resolution

I need a script to copy a specific image depending on the screen resolution being used.
so far I've found that `wmic desktopmonitor get screenheight` is giving me the appropriate output but i'm having trouble parsing it to a useable variable
the problem is that the output is on three lines and I only need the information from the second one.

Can anyone help?

Comment: Show us the code you've tried and are having problems with.

Comment: see here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/25340813/2152082 how to handle the ugly `wmic` line endings. Here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/23067935/2152082 is another way to do it. If you have problems adapting the code to your needs, edit your question with your "best try"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can even get more parameters with one single `wmic`:

```
for /f %%i in ('wmic desktopmonitor get screenheight^,screenwidth /value ^| find "="') do set "%%f"
echo your screen is %screenwidth% * %screenheight% pixels
```

If you need to have your own variablenames, it's a bit more complicated:

```
for /f "tokens=1,2 delims==" %%i in ('wmic desktopmonitor get screenheight^,screenwidth /value ^| find "="') do (
  if "%%i"=="ScreenHeight" set height=%%j
  if "%%i"=="ScreenWidth" set width=%%j
)
echo your screen is %width% * %height% pixels
```

if you need only one value:

```
for /f "tokens=2 delims==" %%i in ('wmic desktopmonitor get screenheight /value ^| find "="') do set height=%%i
echo %height%
```

Comment: Perfect, I did only need the one value for your last FOR loop is ideal.

Comment: One additional challenge though, this works under Windows7 but under 8 it doesn't produce any output.. any ideas for an alternative to WMIC which seems to be broken?

Comment: Might be a permission problem. Try `wmic desktopmonitor get screenheight` If you get an errormessage, try the same in a new cmd-window ("run as administrator") (yes, even if you ARE adminstrator)

Comment: Thanks, but this is a known but with WMIC under Win 8

Answer (score 4):

[@Stephan's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25542832/348501) modified to be compatible with all windows versions (including Windows 8):

```
setlocal
for /f %%i in ('wmic path Win32_VideoController get CurrentHorizontalResolution^,CurrentVerticalResolution /value ^| find "="') do set "%%i"
echo your screen is %CurrentHorizontalResolution% * %CurrentVerticalResolution% pixels
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for /f "tokens=*" %%f in ('wmic desktopmonitor get screenheight /value ^| find "="') do set "%%f"
echo %size%
pause
```

Comment: your `for` will set a variable `%screenheight%`, not `%size%`.